# Manually set value for primary key when saving data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, i am using a legacy database.

```
class Expression < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "EXPRESSION"
set_primary_key "EXP_ID"

belongs_to :sub, :foreign_key => "EXP_SUB_FK"

end
```

To save an entry in the 'EXPRESSION' table, i am using the following code in my controller method:

```
@expression = Expression.create(
                        :EXP_ID => 7,
                        :EXP_SUB_FK => 99991886,
                        :EXP_STRENGTH => 'strong',
                        :EXP_ADDITIONAL_STRENGTH => 'intense',
                        :EXP_COMPONENT_ID => 43444
                       )
```

I have to manually set the EXP_ID each time i save an entry (i will get the id from another table), but the above code does not save the EXP_ID. All the other values are saved except for the EXP_ID.

If i comment out 'set_primary_key "EXP_ID"' in the Expression model, it works but i need to define EXP_ID as primary key.
Is there a way of allocating a value for a primary key when saving an entry to the dbase?

I would be grateful if anyone can provide me with some hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `EXP_ID` in a `before_save` filter defined in the the `Expression` model.

**UPDATE:**

Added Sample:

```
before_save :set_exp_id
def set_exp_id
  self.exp_id = 5555555
end
```

Comment: I added 'before_save :EXP_ID' in my model, but it still does not seem to work

Comment: Thanks Zabba,i finally figured out my error, i missed out the 'self.' in the method